# Model not saving to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm working on a practice API to get used to creating models and routes, but can't seem to get my 1st route to save my data to my MongoDB.

I get the following error from PostMan:

```
{
"message": {
    "errors": {
        "name": {
            "message": "Path `name` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `name` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "name"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "name"
        },
        "description": {
            "message": "Path `description` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `description` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "description"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "description"
        }
    },
    "_message": "Universes validation failed",
    "message": "Universes validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., description: Path `description` is required.",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

}
My model and route look like this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UniverseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date : {
        type:  Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

//export the route ---------------------Name in db , schema that it should use
module.exports = mongoose.model('Universes', UniverseSchema);

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Universe = require('../models/Universe');

// Initial route that will render our universes page
router.get('/', async (req , res) => {
    res.send('Universes Page');
    try {
        const universes = await Universe.find();
        res.json(universes);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error });
    }
});

// Route use to create a universe
// Create async our post 
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Create an instance of the Universe model
    const universe = new Universe({
        name : req.body.name,
        description : req.body.description
    });
    //  Attempt to save our new universe with a try catch
    try {
        const savedUniverse  = await universe.save()
        res.json(savedUniverse);
        console.log('saved');
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error});
        console.log('Not saved');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Whenever i pass my data through Postman I am sending a POST request with an object as such: 
{
"name":"test1",
"description":"test description 1"
}
This is my App.js file - including the body-parser

```
//Server setup
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//index Route
app.get('/' , ( req , res ) => {
    res.send('index');
});
// Import routes
const universeRoute = require('./routes/universes');
app.use('/universes', universeRoute );

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT,
     { useNewUrlParser: true } ,
     () => {
    console.log('Connected to DB');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Appreciate any and all help.

Comment: add body-parser middleware. IT looks like undefine is being received.

Comment: I have the body-parser in my App.js file. Do i need to instantiate it on every route?

Comment: Nope. then try to console the req.body in your save route to check if right data is coming.

Comment: So after doing console.log in a few places, it looks like my async await  / tryCatch may be the issue. The const i create "universe" with the data is parsed properly. But when i try to save the data to mongoDB it just times out.

Comment: In this case, the database is not connected.

Comment: You are a legend my friend. The problem was the way i was importing my .env file. 
I had require('dotenv').config();    instead of    require('dotenv/config');

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely the way you are sending the data to your API, and how it parses it.

Try this:

1. Within Postman, use the most common used method format for sending data via POST requests. This is: "raw" and send the data as application/json. [image: postman post setup]
2. In the API side, make sure you are able to parse application/json requests. The most used package for this withing Express is [expressjs/body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#change-accepted-type-for-parsers)

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const Universe = require('../models/Universe')

const app = express()

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(/* MongoDB connection string */, /* Connection options */);
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
  console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err)
  process.exit(-1)
})

// parse JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))

// Initial route that will render our universes page
app.get('/', async (req , res) => {
  res.send('Universes Page')
  try {
      const universes = await Universe.find()
      res.json(universes)
  } catch (error) {
      res.json({ message: error })
  }
});

// Route use to create a universe
// Create async our post 
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  // Create an instance of the Universe model
  const universe = new Universe({
      name : req.body.name,
      description : req.body.description
  })
  //  Attempt to save our new universe with a try catch
  try {
      const savedUniverse  = await universe.save()
      res.json(savedUniverse)
      console.log('saved')
  } catch (error) {
      res.json({ message: error})
      console.log('Not saved')
  }
});

app.listen(3000)
```

And remember to validate bodies :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the great info. I checked my settings in PostMan and modified it to {application/json}. Unfortunately it still wont save the data im passing through. It seems it goes into the tryCatch block and it gets stuck and i cant figure out why. 

I console.log the "universe" variable and i can see the data inside of it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Solved. Above user mentioned that my DB might not be connected. Looks like my DB_CONNECT variable wasnt actually being imported.

Many thanks for your help though, it helped with my postman issues.

Comment: Happy you managed to get it working. I've update the snippet with Mongoose connection and error logging in case of error.